# Python script to input specified number of element from terminal

Tags: python, raw-input

I am writing a python program in which I want to allow the user to enter only 10 numbers from the terminal. If they try to enter more than 10 it should prompt that they can't enter more than 10 numbers. How can I achieve this in python?

My code looks like as follows:

```
def get_list():
    '''takes data from the user to create a list'''

    error =True

    while error == True:
        error =False
        user_data = raw_input("Please enter integers separated by space:" ) 
        listofdata =user_data.split()
        for item in listofdata:
            try:
                item = int(item)
            except:
                print("Please enter only numbers separated by spaces")
                error =True
                break
    return listofdata
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. In Python, indentation is tantamount to the program's structure, so it is impossible to debug if not indented correctly. Notably, your return statement is at the top level of this sample. If that is accurate, then it would necessarily be part of some enclosing scope that is not even shown here.

Answer (score 1):

After the line:

```
listofdata =user_data.split()
```

you can add a check, something like:

```
if len(listofdata) > 10:
    print "You should enter 10 integers only, please try again!"
    error = True
    continue
```

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.